# extract time from date in php and store in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am making a request to twitter API and I want to extract the time from date in php and store in mysql..Does anyone know how to do that?

The time and date that i get from the results is this ...created_at": "Thu, 26 Jul 2012 22:16:59 +0000"

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Storing timestamps in database

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on PHP side and [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) on MySQL's side.

So basically your code, in short, may look like this:

```php
$twitter_timestamp = 'Thu, 26 Jul 2012 22:16:59 +0000';
$php_time = strtotime($twitter_timestamp);
$query = 'INSERT INTO `some_table` VALUES ("' . $php_time . '");';
```

The above assumes you are storing the timestamp in the column with proper type (`TIMESTAMP`). To read more on differences between `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE` and `DATETIME` see this documentation page: [MySQL Documentation: The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).

### Storing time as string

If you want to store the timestamp in the way that is not timezone-aware (anything else than `TIMESTAMP` and not including timezone information), you will need to form the string representing your timestamp on the PHP side:

```
$twitter_timestamp = 'Thu, 26 Jul 2012 22:16:59 +0000';
$php_time = strtotime($twitter_timestamp);
// Optionally set local timezone:
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$php_timestamp = strftime('%T', $php_time); // will give "%H:%M:%S" timestamp
$query = 'INSERT INTO `some_table` VALUES ("' . $php_timestamp . '");';
```

Note, that [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) call is optional - if you want the time in some specific timezone, different than current. The above assumes you want timestamp in the form of "`HH:MM:SS`".

Comment: thank you but now am getting +1 hour in front in mysql. how can i change that?

Comment: @user1526175: What is the type of the column in the database? It should be `TIMESTAMP`, not `DATETIME`.

Comment: In that case you have to decide on which time zone you want. Your twitter timestamp is in UTC.

Comment: @user1526175: `TIME` is not proper way of storing timezone-aware timestamps. The only way is `TIMESTAMP`, which stores the real timestamp (in Unix epoch) and shows it in the time zone of the MySQL server. `TIME` is just a text field storing values in the `HH:MM:SS` format, so you need to convert your timestamp to the timezone you want on the PHP side.

Comment: so now i get date  and time together. how can i output only the time?

Comment: @user1526175: See updated information, it shows you how to store the hour&minute&second in the format you requested. Vatev is totally correct about the way you can extract time from `TIMESTAMP` column.